# Laravel vite change js functions name after bundle

Tags: laravel, vite

When I use vite to minify js files, all js function names are shortened and I can no longer call those functions. What should I do to prevent the function names from changing?

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/admin.css', 'resources/js/admin.js'],
            refresh: false,
            
        }),
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my vite config :

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@js": "/resources/js/",
        },
    },
    build: {
        css: {
            codeSplit: true,
            assetFileName: "assets/[name].[hash].css",
        },
        rollupOptions: {
            output: {
                // Disable content hashing for filenames
                entryFileNames: "assets/[name].js",
                chunkFileNames: "assets/[name].js",
                assetFileNames: "assets/[name].[ext]",
            },
        },
    },
});
```

the rollupOptions made the build got more consistent file name, but you should check the result first to see the output files name and put them in your code. it's been 2 months now and I frequently build my javascript, the file name is consistent so far.